# Multiple Views within Modal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am attempting to create a modal that has a tab menu, which allows you to switch between views. The reasonable approach seemed to do partial views and build the table using a for each statement; however, they're in different models so I am struggling. I've got the first view working in the modal, but i am unsure how to use different models in each view.

```html
    @model PortalDev.Models.ViewModels.EditUserViewModel
   <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="user-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#user" role="tab" aria-controls="user" aria-selected="true">User</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="roles-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#roles" role="tab" aria-controls="roles" aria-selected="false">Roles</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="claims-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#claims" role="tab" aria-controls="claims" aria-selected="false">Claims</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content tabMenu" id="myTabContent">
 @*----------------------Edit User Role Tab----------------------*@
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="roles" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="roles-tab">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <table class="table table-hover table-md ">

                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-left TableHead">Id</td>
                                        <td class="text-left TableHead">Role</td>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                @*--Table Body For Each to pull DB records--*@
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach (var role in Model.Roles)
                                    {
                                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Administration/Users/UserRoleTable.cshtml", role)
                                    }
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                        @*----------------------Edit User Claims Tab----------------------*@

                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="claims" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="claims-tab">...</div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

------------------UserRoleTable.cshtml-------------------------------------


@model PortalDev.Models.ViewModels.ManageUserRoleViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "UserRoleTable";
}

<tr asp-action="ManageUserRoles" asp-controller="Administration" asp-route-id="@Model.RoleId">
    <td class="text-left">@Model.RoleId</td>
    <td class="text-left">@Model.RoleName</td>

</tr>
```

```c#
    public class ManageUserRoleViewModel
    {

            public string RoleId { get; set; }
            public string RoleName { get; set; }
            public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
            //Viewbag is used to store UserId

    }


---------------EditUserVieModel.cs---------------

      public class EditUserViewModel
    {

        public EditUserViewModel()
        {
            Claims = new List<string>(); Roles = new List<string>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public List<string> Claims { get; set; }

        public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }

    }

----------------AdministrationController.cs (method i need to call)----------


[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ManageUserRoles(string userId)
        {
            ViewBag.userId = userId;

            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {userId} cannot be found";
                return View("NotFound");
            }

            var model = new List<ManageUserRoleViewModel>();

            foreach (var role in roleManager.Roles)
            {
                var manageUserRoleViewModel = new ManageUserRoleViewModel
                {
                    RoleId = role.Id,
                    RoleName = role.Name
                };

                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {
                    manageUserRoleViewModel.IsSelected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    manageUserRoleViewModel.IsSelected = false;
                }
                model.Add(manageUserRoleViewModel);
            }

            return View(model);
        }



I have a users table... I want to be able to click on the user, get the edit modal to come up (works right now). Have 3 sub menu tabs on top. One for editing user info, Second for listing their Roles, Third for listing "claims".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options here. You could use TempData or ViewData dictionaries or your EditUserViewModel needs to contain all the models required to render the entire view along with any partial's it contains.

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
    public ModelClass1 Model1 { get; set; }

    public ModelClass2 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would pass these into the partial views.